# Is there a jQuery slider oncomplete event?

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm using the jQuery slider, where by default the moment the slider is moved something is done with that data, e.g. update the range values.
However, I want to also do something once the user finishes his slide action, e.g. when he moves the slider and then releases it.
How can I execute a function at that moment?

See my pseudo code here, where I added a `complete` event. But which event should I actually use if such an event even exists?

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      values: [ 75, 300 ],
      complete: function(event, ui){
        loadContentviaAjax();
        //do something else
      },
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
  });


<p>
  <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />
</p>

<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

Comment: Did you check the documentation? http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/

Comment: No I did not know of that :) Apparently  I was looking for the `stop` event. Thanks